# Animate height of div based on content with tween()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tween

I'm trying to change the height of a div dynamically based on content. I cracked this with simple CSS earlier using

```
min-height: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
```

However I now need to incorporate this using `tween()` and JavaScript. I currently have:

```
if ( '0px' == middle.getStyle('height') )
    middle.tween('height', '150px'); // needs to be dynamic
else
    middle.tween('height', '0');
```

I'm wondering how I might go about this. Your help would be appreciated.

Here's a fiddle to give you an idea of what I'm trying to do 
http://jsfiddle.net/Cquhj/881/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `height: auto;`?

This will automatichly adapt to the contents inside the div.

Comment: I need to animate it, please have a look at the jsfiddle I added.

Comment: I read your question, and looked at the fiddle, and I still have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: Why would you want to animate the height? Are you going to be inserting more items in the div from the front end?

Comment: If I use auto in the css - it will not hide the div. I'm trying to achieve something similar to this https://www.kainos.com/careers/meet-our-people/

Comment: Try using slideToggle: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/ If this doesn't work I think you should try to find a plugin that is suited for this.

Comment: @GavinFriel did you fix it?